# Why is my table type larger point size than body text when CSS and Inspect Element says it's a +smaller+ point size than body text?

Tags: html, css, html-table, web-inspector

Here's a [link](http://www.publicland.com.au/policy_reform_alt.html) to the page where I have a table with some text in  cells.

HTML of table is:

```
      <p>…committed to fostering the review of policy and law relating to public land.</p>
      <h2>Workshops &nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp; Spring 2013 series</h2>
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr class="table_top row_color_A" >
            <td class="bold_type td" style=" width: 22%; "><a href="/pdf/The_Road_Less_Travelled.pdf">The Road Less Travelled</a></td><td class="td" style="width: 40%; ">Unused, orphaned and otherwise unloved roads</td><td class="td" style="width: 30%">Friday 26 July 2013<br />Monday 29 July 2013</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table_top row_color_B">
            <td class="bold_type td row_color ">Off-Title </td><td class="td">How developments may flow across title boundaries</td><td class="td">Friday 6 Sept 2013</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table_top row_color_A">
            <td class="bold_type td">Bathing Boxes and Boatsheds</td><td class="td">Deficiencies in Coastal Policy and Law</td><td class="td">Friday 20 Sept 2013</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table_top row_color_B">
            <td class="bold_type td">Section 86</td><td class="td">How best to facilitate community management of public land</td><td class="td">Friday 6 Oct 2013</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table_top row_color_A">
            <td class="bold_type td">Road Risk</td><td class="td">The Road Management Act protections against negligence</td><td class="td">Friday 25 Oct 2013</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Relevant CSS style are:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #6685a3;
}

table .table_top {
vertical-align: top;
}

table .bold_type {
    font-weight: bold;       
}

table .td {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 4px 20px 4px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 9pt;
}

table .row_color_A {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    color: #555;
}

table .row_color_B {
    background-color: #9f9f9f;
    color: #444;
}
```

[Link](http://www.publicland.com.au/css/styles.css) to CSS file

Both CSS file and Inspect Element manual inspection say the table text is smaller than the body text Table: 9pt Body:11pt but it's rendering much large than body type.

Got me scratching my head…

Comment: Those are different fonts.

Comment: Why would you write `<td class="td">`?

Comment: Change pt to px. Body has 11px, table has 9pt. Change table font size to 9px

Comment: It's not different fonts. Take out Helvetica and you get same thing. I think the 3rd comment has it sorted. I'm hacking someone else code and mis-read px for pt.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil Careful with statements like that. Those rules may not designate different fonts for you on your particular computer, but on computers that have both Helvetica and Arial installed, they ___are___ different fonts!

Comment: @Mr Lister You have misinterpreted what I said. I could have been clearer, I suppose. Yes, they are different fonts but being different fonts is not the causes of this issue. FYI I have about 4 various Arial and Helvetica families installed and a bunch more in Suitcase at the ready.